# Can I use the record itself in Rails i18n model validation messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, internationalization

I want to provide a useful :length validation message that tells the user how long the current value is. Instead of "Please limit your message to 100 characters," I want to say, "Please limit your message to 100 characters; you currently have 152 characters."

However, it doesn't appear that Rails i18n makes the record itself available for introspection when translating the error message. Is there any way to achieve an i18n message like the following for an ActiveRecord model?

```
too_long: "Maximum %{count} characters. You currently have %{value.length} characters."
```

When I do this, Rails refuses to interpolate "%{value.length}" and just passes it through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may help you:

```
# models/record.rb
class Record < ApplicationRecord
  validates :field, length: { 
    maximum: MAXIMUM_CHARS,
    too_long: I18n.t("errors.messages.too_long",
                count: MAXIMUM_CHARS, current_length: @record.title.length) }
end

# en.yml
too_long: "Maximum %{count} characters. You currently have %{current_length} characters."
```

Comment: This works and is, in fact, what I have been doing. But I was looking for a way to do this without having to explicitly pass the current_length and count in. It would be great if ```@record``` were available within the i18n string, but it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: So it turns out that in Rails 5, there's a new variation in error message construction. You can use a proc that receives the record itself, then construct a string with full access to the model instance. Of course, this doesn't really help with my original issue, which was my wish that arbitrary Ruby code could be executed within `%{replacement_blocks}` in i18n strings. Still, thought I'd point this out: [Rails 5 allows passing record being validated to error message generator](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/07/13/rails-5-allows-passing-record-to-error-message-generator.html)